# Trying to implement ScrollMagic to work with $anchorScroll in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, uiview, scrollmagic, anchor-scroll, ng-app

I decided to use the Single Page Application model - with a seperate `controllers.js`, `services.js` and `app.js` in order to create a website, which would actually stack the views on top of one another, not update the view on view change.

I was basically trying to use the ui-view directive, because I wanted to put the knowledge in a basic example.

The problem I am stumbling upon is the following: I have a `header.html`, in which an anchor `<a></a>` link is pointing to a `div` in another `.html` file. I couldn't get the scroll to work, but somebody on stackoverflow had shown a workaround with `$location.hash('');` and `$anchorScroll`.

In my case this has 2 downsides:

1. I'd like to have a smooth, animated scroll from the anchor to the `div`. I read around and found out this can't be done with the `$anchorScroll`. I was wondering - can `ScrollMagic` be implemented in such a way that it provides scrolling capabilities.
2. Using the `$anchorScroll` method, when scrolling back to the top of the page, and clicking the same anchor, it doesn't work.

---

It's my first post on SO, so any help on how to present you the code in an ordered manner is welcome.